# Removing element from vector by member element

Tags: c++, vector, member

Trying to implement a file system I have 3 classes:

1. BaseFile - Abstract class. Each with a name.
2. File - Inherits from BaseFile. Each file has a size.
3. Directory - Inherits from BaseFile. Holds a:

   ```
   vector<Base File*> children;
   ```

I am trying to build a function that deletes a specific file from a directory using a name as a comparable:

```
for (decltype(children.size()) i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i) {
    if(children[i]->getName() == name) {
        cout << "Same name" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "not found" << endl;
    }
}
```

I have found the elements are similar but how do i delete the one in the vector?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`erase`-`remove_if` idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
children.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        std::begin(children), 
        std::end(children), 
        [&name](const BaseFile* x){ return x->getName() == name; }
    ),
    std::end(children)
);
```

Comment: Where do i use/put this function?

`void Directory::removeFile(string name) {
    children.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                    std::begin(children),
                    std::end(children),
                    [&name](const BaseFile* x){ return x->getName() == name; }
            ),
            std::end(children)
    );
    cout << "Test delete: " << children[0]->getName() << endl;
}

doesn't seem to work. It still prints the name of the child i "deleted"
`